# scrapy with multiple accounts or relogin with a different account (different cookie)

Tags: python, twisted, scrapy

I was crawling a website ,witch strict user`s download pages per day ,about(1000 pages ),after that ,user could not login until tomorrows 0:00.

So I register many accounts to face it.The website did use the cookie.

Here is my  questions ,how to relogin account  when the user is expired and continue crawl the old pages in ‘stack’.
Here is my code may helping you to understand my question.

```
def start_requests(self):
    return [Request(self.start_urls[0], meta = {'cookiejar' : 1}, callback = self.login,dont_filter=True)]

def login(self, response):
    self.account = self.accounts[self.line_count].split(",")
    self.line_count = self.line_count+1
    if(len(self.accounts)<=self.line_count):
        self.line_count = 0;
    self.log('Preparing login:'+self.account[0]+":"+self.account[1].rstrip())
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,   
                        meta = {'cookiejar' : response.meta['cookiejar']},
                        headers = self.headers, 
                        formdata = {
                        'j_email': self.account[0],
                        'j_password': self.account[1].rstrip(),
                        'submit': 'Ok'
                        },
                        callback = self.parse_url,
                        dont_filter = True,
                        )]
```

And when i face the Problems below ,I will start_request again ,but it did not work  or missed much of pages(with the same error like session has expired).

```
def parse_page_imo(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    loginfail = hxs.xpath('//table[@class="tab"]/tbody/tr/td/div[@id="encart"]/li/text()').extract()

    if loginfail==([u'Your login (e-mail) or/and password are unknown in Equasis. Please, try again']):
        print "relogin"
        self.start_requests()
    if loginfail==([u'Your session has expired, please try to login again']):
        print "relogin"
        self.start_requests()
    if loginfail==([u'You have been disconnected or your login/password is unknown in Equasis. Please, try again.']):
        print "relogin"
        self.start_requests()
    if loginfail==([u'By security, your session has been cancelled.']):
        print "relogin"
        self.start_requests()
  ....codes to parse items....
```

here is my hole codes:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from imo_dlcosco_ships.settings import URLS, COOKIES, HEADER
from imo_dlcosco_ships.items import ShipListItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import time

class EquasisSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'imo_202'
    allowed_domains = ["www.equasis.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.equasis.org/EquasisWeb/public/HomePage",
    ]

    def __init__(self): 
        self.headers = HEADER
        self.cookies = COOKIES
        self.urls = URLS
        f = open("account.txt", "r")
        self.accounts = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        self.line_count = 0



    #login
    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(self.start_urls[0], meta = {'cookiejar' : 1}, callback = self.login,dont_filter=True)]

    def login(self, response):
        self.account = self.accounts[self.line_count].split(",")
        self.line_count = self.line_count+1
        if(len(self.accounts)<=self.line_count):
            self.line_count = 0;
        self.log('Preparing login:'+self.account[0]+":"+self.account[1].rstrip())
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,   
                            meta = {'cookiejar' : response.meta['cookiejar']},
                            headers = self.headers, 
                            formdata = {
                            'j_email': self.account[0],
                            'j_password': self.account[1].rstrip(),
                            'submit': 'Ok'
                            },
                            callback = self.parse_url,
                            dont_filter = True,
                            )]


    def parse_url(self, response):
        return [FormRequest(url="http://www.equasis.org/EquasisWeb/restricted/ShipSearchAdvanced?fs=ShipSearch",   
                           meta = {'cookiejar' : response.meta['cookiejar']},
                            headers = self.headers, 
                            cookies = self.cookies,
                            formdata = {
                            'P_PAGE': '1'
                            },
                            dont_filter = True,
                            callback = self.parse_imo_url,
                            )]
    def parse_imo_url(self, response):
        return [FormRequest(url="http://www.equasis.org/EquasisWeb/restricted/ShipList?fs=ShipSearch",   
                            meta = {'cookiejar' : response.meta['cookiejar']},
                            headers = self.headers, 
                            cookies = self.cookies,
                            formdata = {
                            'P_CLASS_ST_rb':'HC',
                            'P_CLASS_rb':'HC',
                            'P_CatTypeShip':'6',
                            'P_CatTypeShip_p2':'6',
                            'P_CatTypeShip_rb':'CM',
                            'P_DW_GT':'250000',
                            'P_DW_LT':'999999',
                            'P_FLAG_rb':'HC',
                            'P_PAGE':'1',
                            'Submit':'SEARCH'
                            },
                            dont_filter = True,
                            callback = self.parse_page_num,
                            )]

    def parse_page_num(self,response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        loginfail = hxs.xpath('//table[@class="tab"]/tbody/tr/td/div[@id="encart"]/li/text()').extract()

        if loginfail==([u'Your login (e-mail) or/and password are unknown in Equasis. Please, try again']):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        if loginfail==([u'Your session has expired, please try to login again']):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        if loginfail==([u'You have been disconnected or your login/password is unknown in Equasis. Please, try again.']):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        if loginfail==([u'By security, your session has been cancelled.']):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        htmlurl = response._url.split('?')[0]
        f = open('page.html','a')
        f.write(response.body)
        f.close()   
        if(htmlurl=='http://www.equasis.org/EquasisWeb/restricted/ShipList'):
            temp1 = hxs.xpath('//form[@name="form"]/table[@class="tab"]/tbody/tr/td[@align="right"]/span/a/@onclick').extract()
            temp2 = temp1[len(temp1)-1].split(";document")[0]
            PageNum = temp2.split("P_PAGE.value=")[1].encode("utf-8")

            for h in range(int(PageNum)):
                yield FormRequest(url="http://www.equasis.org/EquasisWeb/restricted/ShipList?fs=ShipList",
                                meta={'cookiejar' : response.meta['cookiejar'],'pageNum':str(h+1)},
                                headers = self.headers, 
                                cookies = self.cookies,
                                formdata = {
                                'P_CALLSIGN':'',
                                'P_IMO':'',
                                'P_NAME':'',
                                'P_PAGE':'%d' %(h+1)         
                                },
                                dont_filter = True,
                                callback = self.parse_page_imo     
                                )
    def parse_page_imo(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        loginfail = hxs.xpath('//table[@class="tab"]/tbody/tr/td/div[@id="encart"]/li/text()').extract()
        if(loginfail==([u'Your login (e-mail) or/and password are unknown in Equasis. Please, try again'])):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        if(loginfail == [u'Your session has expired, please try to login again']):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        if(loginfail == [u'You have been disconnected or your login/password is unknown in Equasis. Please, try again.']):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        if(loginfail == [u'By security, your session has been cancelled.']):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()


        htmlurl = response._url.split('?')[0]
        if(htmlurl=='http://www.equasis.org/EquasisWeb/restricted/ShipList'):

            item = ShipListItem()
            shipNameHtml = hxs.xpath('//form[@name="formShip"]/table[@class="tab"]/tbody/tr/td[1]').extract()
            shipHtmlTitle = Selector(text=shipNameHtml[0]).xpath('//text()').extract()
            if(shipHtmlTitle[0].find('Name of ship')>-1):
                item['ship_name'] = hxs.xpath('//form[@name="formShip"]/table[@class="tab"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/text()').extract()
            onclickValue = hxs.xpath('//form[@name="formShip"]/table[@class="tab"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/@onclick').extract()
            for i in range(len(onclickValue)):
                onclickValue2 = onclickValue[i].split(";document")[0]
                onclickValue3 = onclickValue2.split("P_IMO.value=")[1].encode("utf-8")
                onclickValue[i] = onclickValue3.strip('\'')
            item['imo'] = onclickValue


            for h in range(len(item['imo'])):
                p_imo = item['imo'][h]
                ShipName = item['ship_name'][h]
                p_imo = p_imo.rstrip()
                yield FormRequest("http://www.equasis.org/EquasisWeb/restricted/ShipInfo?fs=ShipList",   
                                meta = {'cookiejar' : response.meta['cookiejar'],'P_imo':p_imo,'ShipName':ShipName},
                                headers = self.headers, 
                                cookies = self.cookies,
                                formdata = {
                                'P_IMO': p_imo
                                },
                                dont_filter = True,
                                callback = self.parse_page_mmsi,
                                )

    def parse_page_mmsi(self,response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        loginfail = hxs.xpath('//table[@class="tab"]/tbody/tr/td/div[@id="encart"]/li/text()').extract()
        if(loginfail==([u'Your login (e-mail) or/and password are unknown in Equasis. Please, try again'])):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        if(loginfail == [u'Your session has expired, please try to login again']):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        if(loginfail == [u'You have been disconnected or your login/password is unknown in Equasis. Please, try again.']):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        if(loginfail == [u'By security, your session has been cancelled.']):
            print "relogin"
            self.start_requests()
        shipHtml = hxs.xpath('//table[@class="encart"]/tbody/tr').extract()
        item=ShipListItem()
        item['mmsi'] = [u'']
        for j in range(len(shipHtml)):  
            shipHtmlTitle = Selector(text=shipHtml[j]).xpath('//td[1]/text()').extract()
            if(shipHtmlTitle[0].find('MMSI :')>-1):
                item['mmsi'] = Selector(text=shipHtml[j]).xpath('//td[2]/text()').extract()
        item['imo'] = response.meta['P_imo']
        item['ship_name']  = response.meta['ShipName']
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finially i solve my problem . I wrote an downloadMiddleware to handle it 。 when login error occurs, i paused the spider and queue all the next request and relogin,then resume the spider .and everything seems ok.

Comment: whould you share your midlware?

Answer (score 0):

The [`start_requests`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) method is expected to return an iterable of `scrapy.Request` objects. Simply calling it inside your response callback `parse_page_imo` merely gets you a temporary value. You shall at least return or yield the values, for example:

```
for req in self.start_requests():
    yield req
```

**EDITED:** Also in your response callback `login`, the return value shall be request objects (instead of a list), too.

Comment: I had tried to replace start_requests() with yield [Request(self.start_urls[0], meta = {'cookiejar' : 1}, callback = self.login,dont_filter=True)].   but it did not help .And I dont think  it should be the direct resolution to my problem

Comment: @sacuba *1.* You are *not* doing it right: in my example it was `yield`ing a single request object while you tried to `yield` a `list`. And `scrapy` does not handle `list`s from response callbacks. *2.* You have posted only part of your code (e.g. what exact is the website? where is your `parse_page_imo` invoked?) and people here have no way to know what a direct solution you think is. *3.* At least it is a problem, and problems are solved one by one.

Comment: I got your point ,it`s my fault to return a list not an iterable of Request objects . I feel sorry about my mistake. Also,  i add the hole codes( not change the 'return fault',may be the original code may help you to understand my question ) in my Question.   Look forward to your kind reply, thank you !

Comment: finially i solve my problem . I wrote an downloadMiddleware to handle it 。 when login error occurs, i paused the spider and queue all the next request and relogin,then resume the spider .and everything seems ok. Thank you for your prior answer.